# How do I ensured all pointers are freed?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, vector, smart-pointers

I have a class. Let's call it House. Houses of various properties are contained in a registry. Let's call this house registry. Within this class, I want to add a vector containing pointers to different houses sorted in different ways(perhaps by name and number). Within this class, I have a function that creates new House objects and inserts them in the respective order. In doing so I'm leaving memory leaks as the program may terminate in a myriad of ways but doesn't free up memory stored in the vector. I know I can use smart pointers. But how do I implement them in the right way? I'm intentionally leaving out the destructor as its implementation is fairly obvious. But this question is specifically about smart pointers. A great answer would preferably include their implementation with comparators.

```
class HouseRegistry{
    struct House{
    ....
    }
private:
    vector<House*>HousesbyName;
    vector<House*>HousesbyNumber

    bool newHouse(...){
        House *somehouse = new House;
        ....
        HousesbyName.insert(inserter,somehouse);
        HousesbyNumber.insert(inserter2,somehouse);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I know a solution might look something like

```
class HouseRegistry{
    struct House{
        ....
    }
private:
    vector<shared_ptr<House>>HousesbyName;
    vector<shared_ptr<House>>HousesbyNumber

    bool newHouse(...){
        auto somehouse = make_shared<House>();
        ....
        HousesbyName.insert(inserter,somehouse);
        HousesbyNumber.insert(inserter2,somehouse);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But it breaks for functions like Binary Search when the comparator function uses two House pointers as arguments. What would a subsequent comparator function look like in this case if looking for any preexisting occurrence of a house?

Comment: In modern c++ you do that by never using `new` a second way is to use one of the smart pointers to free the memory for you.

Comment: "*I know I can use smart pointers*" - so, then what is the problem exactly? Any decent C++ book/tutorial should cover this.

Comment: You mostly answered your own question by saying "I know I can use smart pointers". Indeed you can. You can avoid leaking memory by never calling `new` in the first place. Given what is shown here, `std::shared_ptr<House>` *may* be the best element type for your containers. Can't really say with certainty though, since what little is shown is so abstract.

Comment: @RemyLebeau " But how do I implement them in the right way?" That is what follows next. I tried using shared_ptr and unique_ptr and they simply break the program when used as type classifiers for the vectors. I can still leave the vectors as vector <House*>... but then the values don't get inserted.

Comment: @Onlyartist9 break in what way? You should [edit] your question to include that info.

Comment: Will do @RemyLebeau

Comment: "this question is specifically about smart pointers", and this question is, specifically, what exactly? Smart pointers are not complicated, hard to comprehend concept. When it comes down to smart pointers, it's mostly "check your brain at the door" situation. The only thing to watch out for is to avoid circular referneces. Otherwise, the smart pointers do all the work for you, and you have nothing else to think about.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I edited the question to add more detail.

Comment: Again, you state a problem, without actually explaining it. What does "breaks for functions like Binary Search when the comparator function uses two House pointers as arguments" mean? Your final question of what would a binary search-friendly comparator function for std::shared_ptr look like sounds reasonable, but is 180 degrees to the opposite of what was originally asked, a generic question about manual dynamic memory management, that other people already invested their time answering. A classic example of an XY problem.

Comment: @Onlyartist9 "*But it breaks for functions like Binary Search when the comparator function uses two House pointers as arguments*" - simply change the comparator to take two smart pointers as arguments instead. "*What would a subsequent comparator function look like in this case*" - please show the comparator you are having trouble with? But, since you are struggling to understand smart pointers in general, you should learn about them by themselves first, then introduce container use later.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<House>> HousesbyName;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<House>> HousesbyNumber
```

```
auto somehouse = std::make_shared<House>();
...
HousesbyName.insert(inserter, somehouse);
HousesbyNumber.insert(inserter2, somehouse);
...
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau The answer is great but I added a bit more detail to clarify the problem. So if there's an updated answer on the way, would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I ensured all pointers are freed?

In general: By always freeing every dynamic allocation after you no longer need them.

The general answer is simple, and following it isn't easy. There are ways to make it easier in different cases. The easiest way is to not use dynamic allocation manually at all in the first place. Your example doesn't necessarily demonstrate a need for it. You could use `std::vector<House>` to store the objects. Alternatively, your use cases seems appropriate for a multi-index container. The standard doesn't provide a multi-index container template, but Boost does.

But in case where you do need dynamic allocation, a simple way to avoid leaks is to never use `new`, `std::malloc` etc. and instead use containers or `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` and never call `std::unique_ptr::release`.

Comment: "*Your example doesn't necessarily demonstrate a need for [dynamic allocation]*" - except that the example is maintaining 2 vectors that point to the same objects, so there is a need for pointers. But you are right that they don't necessarily need to be pointers to *dynamically allocated* objects. For instance, using a 3rd `vector<House>`, and then 2 `vector<House*>` for sorting the 1st vector

Comment: @RemyLebeau Or alternatively the `std::vector<House>` may have one sorting and the `std::vector<House*>` has the other. The obvious caveat is that the vector containing the `House` objects must be sorted before creating the pointer vector.